# Detecting when a YouTube video has finished playing

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-mediaplayer, android-youtube-api

How to do I check when a YouTube video has finished playing in the official YouTube Android app? In the LogCat I see things such as: VideoStage: MEDIA_PLAYING_VIDEO. Is there any way to detect when this finishes?

Comment: I am pretty sure that would require Youtube to send out a broadcast at the end of it's videos since it uses it's own media player, and I doubt that happens.

Comment: Never say never @zgc7009 ;)

Comment: @Tukajo Hats off to you, it really surprises me that they implemented that in their API :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`MediaPlayer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html). It has an `isPlaying` method to check if music/videos are currently playing. Just set a `Boolean` to true while it's playing and check the `isPlaying` method against that `Boolean` to see if it changed from `True` to `False`.

Otherwise Youtube (or google) may have some specific API's

EDIT:

I looked into [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener); and it appears that there is an API for youtube.

you can use the method `PlayerStateChangeListener` for the `YoutubePlayer`class to get the listener and implement the method `OnVideoEnded`

Comment: I was thinking about checking if the audio was playing or not, but that is a bit of a hack. As to the API, my app is not playing the video, but rather the official app. Do you think the API would still work?

Comment: Is your app pushed to background as it opens the youtube app?

Comment: I'd imagine it would be easier to just implement your own custom youtube xml layout that way you get the look and feel of the youtube app but you don't lose the ability to use the youtube api. I am not sure if you can check status of audio or video from one app to another

Comment: Yes. My app simply opens the link in the YouTube app.

Comment: That way (doing what I said) you can just have the link pass to the xml layout's code. Heck you could even make it a fragment and reuse it multiple times in the app

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll use your suggestions to see what I can do!